# Добавить/убрать класс, через интервал времени у всех дочерних элементов при наведении на родительский

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько элементов, при наведении на которые у дочерних должен добавляться класс по очереди через промежуток времени.

Добавить класс при наведении смог, а когда увожу мышь с родителя класс сначала убирается, а потом снова зачем-то добавляется, не пойму в чем дело.

```js
$('.field_icon')
  .mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children('.field-item').each(function(i, el) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).addClass('active');
      }, 100 + (i * 300));
    })
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('.field-item').removeClass('active')
  })
```

```css
.field-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #7CB342;
}
.field-item.active {
  background: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_icon">
  <div class="field-item"></div>
  <div class="field-item"></div>
  <div class="field-item"></div>
  <div class="field-item"></div>
</div>
<div class="field_icon">
  <div class="field-item"></div>
  <div class="field-item"></div>
  <div class="field-item"></div>
  <div class="field-item"></div>
</div>
<div class="field_icon">
  <div class="field-item"></div>
  <div class="field-item"></div>
</div>
<div class="field_icon">
  <div class="field-item"></div>
  <div class="field-item"></div>
  <div class="field-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так вот будет работать (первый раз выложил, не заметил один баг, теперь работает, появляется и пропадает):

```
    <script>
    var timers = [];
    $('.field_icon')
            .mouseover(function() {
                ClearTimeOutTimer();
                $(this).children('.field-item').each(function(i, el) {
                    timers[i] = setTimeout(function() {
                        $(el).addClass('active');
                    }, 100 + (i * 300));
                })
            }).mouseleave(function() {
        ClearTimeOutTimer();
        $(this).children('.field-item').removeClass('active')
    });
    function ClearTimeOutTimer(){

        timers.map(function (timeOut) {
            if(timeOut) {
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Обрати внимание, что если мышь увести влево, то заполняются только те что не заполнились до mouseleave. Если вниз, то mouseover, видимо срабатывает заново.

Еще момент, попробуй сохранить timerId в каждый элемент и при mouseleave брать из чилдов timerId и делать clearTimeout чтобы не продолжали отрабатывать остальные таймеры после mouseleave